# Как удалить определенные символы в начале и конце строки, если они есть?

Tags: php

Пример: имеем массив, в нем в каждой строке может быть открывающая и закрывающая кавычка, вот такая: `'`

Как их удалить, если они имеются и не трогать строку, если их нет?

Comment: используйте функцию `trim($item, '\'')` в теле цикла.

Comment: А если они в середине, то удалять не нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел удобное решение в английской части стака.

```
    /**
    * Удаляет кавычки в начале и конце строки, если они есть
    *
    * @param mixed $text
    */
    function stripQuotes($text) {
      $unquoted = preg_replace('/^(\'(.*)\'|"(.*)")$/', '$2$3', $text);
      return $unquoted;
    }
```

Пример работы:

```
     Исходная строка    Вывод
     --------------------------------
     No quotes       => No quotes
     "Double quoted" => Double quoted
     'Single quoted' => Single quoted
     "One of each'   => "One of each'
     "Multi""quotes" => Multi""quotes
     '"'"@";'"*&^*'' => "'"@";'"*&^*'
```

Comment: если нужно удалять только вначале и в конце, то нет смысла юзать регексы.